# SOLR 8: Not able to query field content

Tags: solr

I am new to SOLR. I managed to create a core and upload a pdf file. The content of PDF file is stored in "content" field, which is value is set to true for `indexed="true"` `stored="true"` `multiValued="true"`.

My issue is that the query does not return any value of that particular field. Can anyone shed some light about it? Thanks.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*",
      "_":"1567041472211"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"E:\\solr-8.2.0\\solr-8.2.0\\example\\exampledocs\\1.pdf",
        "date":["2019-08-27T05:11:41Z"],
        "pdf_pdfversion":[1.7],
        "xmp_creatortool":["Microsoft® Word for Office 365"],
        "stream_content_type":["application/pdf"],
        "access_permission_modify_annotations":[true],
        "access_permission_can_print_degraded":[true],
        "language":["en-AU"],
        "dcterms_created":["2019-08-27T05:11:41Z"],
        "last_modified":["2019-08-27T05:11:41Z"],
        "dcterms_modified":["2019-08-27T05:11:41Z"],
        "dc_format":["application/pdf; version=1.7"],
        "xmpmm_documentid":["uuid:BFD10F3D-FA4F-4804-9A10-B0E1B9A9FCE0"],
        "last_save_date":["2019-08-27T05:11:41Z"],
        "pdf_docinfo_creator_tool":["Microsoft® Word for Office 365"],
        "access_permission_fill_in_form":[true],
        "pdf_docinfo_modified":["2019-08-27T05:11:41Z"],
        "meta_save_date":["2019-08-27T05:11:41Z"],
        "pdf_encrypted":[false],
        "modified":["2019-08-27T05:11:41Z"],
        "content_type":["application/pdf"],
        "stream_size":[2453521],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser"],
        "dc_language":["en-AU"],
        "meta_creation_date":["2019-08-27T05:11:41Z"],
        "created":["2019-08-27T05:11:41Z"],
        "access_permission_extract_for_accessibility":[true],
        "access_permission_assemble_document":[true],
        "xmptpg_npages":[528],
        "creation_date":["2019-08-27T05:11:41Z"],
        "resourcename":["E:\\solr-8.2.0\\solr-8.2.0\\example\\exampledocs\\1.pdf"],
        "access_permission_extract_content":[true],
        "access_permission_can_print":[true],
        "producer":["Microsoft® Word for Office 365"],
        "access_permission_can_modify":[true],
        "pdf_docinfo_producer":["Microsoft® Word for Office 365"],
        "pdf_docinfo_created":["2019-08-27T05:11:41Z"],
        "content":[" \n \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n \n    \n  \n \n Prepared by the Office of Parliamentary Counsel, Canberra \n \n  \n \n Competition and Consumer Act 2010 \n \n No. 51, 1974 \n \n Compilation No. 118 \n \n Compilation date:   6 April 2019 \n \n Includes amendments up to: Act No. 49, 2019 \n \n Registered:    23 April 2019 \n \n This compilation is in 3 volumes \n \n Volume 1: sections 1–110 \n \n Volume 2: sections 10.01–185 \n \n Volume 3: Schedules \n \n   Endnotes \n \n Each volume has its own contents \n  \n  \n \n   \n  \n \n \n \n  \n \n About this compilation \n \n This compilation \n \n This is a compilation of the Competition and Consumer Act 2010 that shows the \n \n text of the law as amended and in force on 6 April 2019 (the compilation date). \n \n The notes at the end of this compilation (the endnotes) include information \n \n about amending laws and the amendment history of provisions of the compiled \n \n law. \n \n Uncommenced amendments \n \n The effect of uncommenced amendments is not shown in the text of the \n \n compiled law. Any uncommenced amendments affecting the law are accessible \n \n on the Legislation Register (www.legislation.gov.au).
```

Comment: there is content field at the last...its has some text...what is the exact issue here?

Comment: Hi Abhijit, the last field "Content" contained pdf content. My understanding is that if I enter keyword/query such as "consumers" or "volumes", they will return result and highlighted in the text. Not just returning the metadata of the pdf file itself like what is presented. The content is what I am interested in. Imagine if we use ctrl+f in windows...I am thinking it will return the query and hightlight those keywords even if there are multiple pdf document? Unless I misunderstood how the search engine work and how it is displayed

Comment: your current query is the default one "*:*"...you should query to specific field like q=context:"text" and for highlighting there are some paramas like hl=true&hl.fl=content etc..please refer the solr documents for the same at https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/highlighting.html

Comment: Hi Abhijit, at the moment the query is standard and only returning document level metadata. I think I have found my solution, which is TermsComponent (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SOLR/TermsComponent) TermVectorComponent (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SOLR/TermVectorComponent). I will update again to see if it works. I want the query to return content of a field (not just at document level)